# How can you make a python histogram percentage sum to 100%?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am struggling to make a histogram plot where the total percentage of events sums to 100%. Instead, for this particular example, it sums to approximately 3%. Will anyone be able to show me how I make the percentages of my events sum to 100% for any array used?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
import numpy as np
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
data = np.array([0,9,78,6,44,23,88,77,12,29])
length_of_data = len(data)          # Length of data
bins = int(np.sqrt(length_of_data)) # Choose number of bins
y = data

plt.title('Histogram')
plt.ylabel('Percentage Of Events')
plt.xlabel('bins')
plt.hist(y,bins=bins, density = True)
plt.show()
print(bins)
```

Comment: Why don't you scale the values on the y axis by 100/3?

Comment: See seaborn's `sns.histplot(..., stat='percent')` ([docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it is to get the bin heights that `plt.hist` returns, then re-set the patch heights to the normalized height you want. It's not *that* involved if you know what to do, but not that ideal. Here's your case:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
import numpy as np

plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(100))    # <-- changed here
data = np.array([0,9,78,6,44,23,88,77,12,29])
length_of_data = len(data)          # Length of data
bins = int(np.sqrt(length_of_data)) # Choose number of bins
y = data

plt.title('Histogram')
plt.ylabel('Percentage Of Events')
plt.xlabel('bins')
#### Setting new heights
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(y, bins=bins, density = True, edgecolor='k')
scaled_n = n / n.sum() * 100
for new_height, patch in zip(scaled_n, patches):
    patch.set_height(new_height)
####
# Setting cumulative sum as verification
plt.plot((bins[1:] + bins[:-1])/2, scaled_n.cumsum())
# If you want the cumsum to start from 0, uncomment the line below
#plt.plot(np.concatenate([[0], (bins[1:] + bins[:-1])/2]), np.concatenate([[0], scaled_n.cumsum()]))
plt.ylim(top=110)
plt.show()
```

This is the resulting picture: [image]

As others said, you can use `seaborn`. Here's how to reproduce my code above. You'd still need to add all the labels and styling you want.

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.histplot(data, bins=int(np.sqrt(length_of_data)), stat='percent')
sns.histplot(data, bins=int(np.sqrt(length_of_data)), stat='percent', cumulative=True, element='poly', fill=False, color='C1')
```

This is the resulting picture: [image]